# major(stat.st_rdev) and minor(stat.st_rdev) on non-device files

Tags: c, linux, stat

Simple questions: in Linux, I `stat()` a file that is not a device. what is the expected value of the `st_rdev` field? Is it ok for me to run `major(stat.st_rdev)` and `minor(stat.st_rdev)`? If so, what are the expected return values?

Code example:

```
struct stat sstat = stat("myfileordevice");
ProcessFileOrDevice("myfileordevice",
                    sstat.st_mode,
                    major(stat.st_rdev),
                    minor(stat.st_rdev));
```

Comment: The `st_rdev` field will be there whether it's a device or not... and `major()` and `minor()` macros will probably still work... but the values will be garbage for non-devices so you can't really use the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What value `stat.st_rdev` should have if I `stat()` a non-device filesystem entry?

It depends on the filesystem that the entry is on. The internal structures and functions in Linux (such as[`fs/stat.c`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/stat.c)) allow each filesystem to define the values.

In general, the value should be zero. Quick testing (`stat -c '%t:%T' some-files-and-directories`) indicates it tends to be. I just cannot find any guarantees or claims it *should be* zero.

> Is it safe to use `major(stat.st_rdev)` and minor(stat.st_rdev)

Of course; they only apply some arithmetic to the specified value, and return the result.

Personally, I'd be inclined to use something like

```
    unsigned int maj, min;
    struct stat  info;

    /* stat(), fstat(), fstatat() or something
       to fill the info buffer */

    if (S_ISCHR(info.st_mode) || S_ISBLK(info.st_mode)) {
        maj = major(info.st_rdev);
        min = minor(info.sr_rdev);
    } else {
        maj = 0U;
        min = 0U;
    }

    ProcessFileOrDevice("myfileordevice", info.st_mode, maj, min);
```

just to make sure. Note that the `ProcessFileOrDevice()` function could just as well do the check itself, and ignore `maj` and `min` values unless `S_ISCHR(info.st_mode)` or `S_ISBLK(info.st_mode)` values are true.

The [`man 2 stat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fstat.2.html) man page contains further useful details.